# display info according to the logged-in user by checking the employeeID

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, active-directory

I am using active directory to authenticate the user.
Now I am using the below php to store the Employee_id of the user who has logged in :

```html
if(isset($data[$i]["employeeid"][0]))
{
$user= $data[$i]["employeeid"][0];
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=$user;
}
```

Now after authentication the user is taken to the profile .
In the profile I want to echo selected information based on the the user who has logged in.

So I am using the below php to select an user according to their employee_id and echo the info:

```html
<div id="co-workers" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">

<div class="leaderboard">
  <?php  if ( $_SESSION['id'] == '1981')?> {
  <ol>
    <li>
        <mark>
      <?php while( $toprow77 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt7) ) {

        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow77['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow77['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow77['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

      } ?>
       </mark>
      </li>

  </ol>

}   <?php  if ( $_SESSION['id'] == '100739')?> {
<ol>
<li>
<mark>
 <?php while( $toprow20 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt20) ) {

echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow20['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow20['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow20['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

}?>

</mark>
</li>

</ol>
} <?php  if ( $_SESSION['id'] == '603')?> {
<ol>
<li>
<mark>
 <?php while( $toprow19 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt19) ) {

echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow19['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow19['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow19['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

}?>

</mark>
</li>

</ol>
}

</div>
</div>
```

**problem :** when I run the above PHP it echoes for all the three Employee_ids.It is not entering the if else statements and selecting the employee_ID and displaying info of only the user who has logged in.
The logged in user's ID is saved in the first PHP snippet I have mentioned above.

I tried using -  **if ,elseif ,else** also.

Comment: you have to clear your session variables when you logged out from the system.

Comment: I understand that.I dont think its related to that.In the page where I am authenticating the user,in that I have stored the employee_id.Then I am using that variable in the above PHP to select which user has logged in and echo only that user's data. I think I am making some mistake with the php.Anyways,thanks for the input.God bless.

Comment: In the above php, it should enter the if else statements and display only thye relevant info.

Comment: try using === instead of ==

Comment: @Omi thanks for the input.It didnot work.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution using switch statements,which works perfect :

```html
<div class="leaderboard">
  <?php switch ($_SESSION['id']) {
    case "1981":?>
  <ol>
    <li>
        <mark>
       <?php while( $toprow77 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt7) ) {

        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow77['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow77['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow77['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

      } ?>
       </mark>
      </li>

  </ol>

 <?php break;
  case "100739" : ?>
<ol>
<li>
<mark>
<?php while( $toprow20 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt20) ) {

echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow20['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow20['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow20['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

}?>

</mark>
</li>

</ol>

<?php
 break;

}
?>



</div>
```